# Is it possible to use vars from .ini into sass files?

Tags: webpack, sass, ini

To avoid config file duplicated, I wish doing only one `config.ini`.
My problem is how to use variables in `style.sass` from `config.ini` instead of `config.sass`.

For the moment I got this :

**config.sass**

```
/* Configuration variables
$theme-name: "My Theme"
$author: "Robinson"
$author-uri: "https://robinson.org"
$description: "Specific theme for \"My Theme\""
```

**style.sass**

```
@import "../themes/config/config"
/*!
 Theme Name: #{$theme-name}
 Author: #{$author}
 Author URI: #{$author-uri}
 Description: #{$description}
```

I would like to use

**config.ini**

```
theme-name=My Theme
author=Robinson
author-uri=https://robinson.org
description=Specific theme for \"My Theme\"
```

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution based on [prependData of sass loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader#prependdata).

**webpack.config.js**

```
const GENERAL_CONFIG_INI = "../config/config.ini";
const THEME_CONFIG_INI = "./config/config.ini";

const path = require('path');
const Promise = require('bluebird');
const fs = Promise.promisifyAll( require('fs') );
const ini = require('ini');
// include the css extraction and minification plugins
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

const global_config = ini.parse( fs.readFileSync( GENERAL_CONFIG_INI, 'utf-8' ) );
const theme_config = ini.parse( fs.readFileSync( THEME_CONFIG_INI, 'utf-8' ) );

var a_author_uri = global_config.author_uri.split(":");
var author_protocol = a_author_uri[0];
var author_uri_without_protocol = a_author_uri[1].replace( "//", "" );
var a_author_uri_domain = author_uri_without_protocol.split(".");
var author_uri_domain_name, author_uri_extension;
if( a_author_uri_domain.length === 3 ){
    author_uri_domain_name = a_author_uri_domain[1];
    author_uri_extension = a_author_uri_domain[2];
}else if( a_author_uri_domain.length === 2 ){
    author_uri_domain_name = a_author_uri_domain[0];
    author_uri_extension = a_author_uri_domain[1];
}
module.exports = {
    entry: './dev/next/style.sass',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/'),
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            // compile all .scss files to plain old css
            {
                test: /style.sass$/,
                use: [ { loader : MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader },
                    { loader: 'css-loader' },
                    {
                        loader: 'sass-loader',
                        options: {
                            prependData: '$theme-name: ' + theme_config.theme_infos.name +
                                ';$author:' + global_config.author +
                                ';$author-uri-protocol:' + author_protocol+
                                ';$author-uri-domain:' + author_uri_domain_name +
                                ';$author-uri-extension:' + author_uri_extension +
                                ';$description:' +  theme_config.theme_infos.description.replace(/:/g, "%3A").replace(/;/g, "%3B") + ';',
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        // extract css into dedicated file
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: './next/style.css'
        })
    ]
};
```